# Not aligned text without any package

Tags: line-breaking, margins

## Problem

I was working on a project, when suddenly, just one word didn't follow the rules of margins, without any reason. I thought it was some package error, but it seems like this is a 1 in a million error.

The problem is that in one specific setup, the line doesn't break with the characteristic `-`, for example in the word "something" should be `some-` and in the next line `thing`. Here is an image:

[image]

And again I'm not using packages although the colors look diferent, I only use `\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry}` for the margins. I tried diferent things but they don't work;

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Main Code

```
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry}
...
\chapter*{Prefacio}
\noindent La técnica de la taquigrafía ha sido realmente útil en el pasado, pero ahora,
la mecanografia es una forma sencilla de expresar
...
```

## Full Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Prefacio}
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.\\

\noindent La técnica de la taquigrafía ha sido realmente útil en el pasado, pero ahora, la mecanografía es una forma sencilla de expresar conocimientos realmente rápido, hasta 150 palabras por minuto con mucha práctica. blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla aun así...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you extend your code into a small example that people can compile please? Difficult to help without having MWE to troubleshoot and diagnose issues with :)

Comment: Most likely: The word was long, and at the end of a line, and TeX did not know how to hyphenate it. Are you using hyphenation patterns for your language? If not, install them. But if hyphenation is available, and the word exceeds the margin, then you must hyphenate it manually, or re-write the paragraph.

Comment: " I thought it was some package error, but it seems like this is a 1 in a million error."  not an error at all  it is quite common, the log file will have given details with an overfull box warning. You have not shown any relevant code but check you have specified the language and T1 font encoding

Comment: I get `Overfull \hbox (14.45116pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10`, is quite common, alsin in `Overfull \hbox (6.1304pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--8` (the dot). And `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 7--8`

Comment: with your edit you have confirmed you are using English rules add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepakage[spanish]{babel}`

Comment: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) ` is from `\\ ` never have that at the end of a paragraph

Comment: Add a discretionary hyphen at the likely breakpoint; for this word, I'd suggest `...no\-gra...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the language, and T1 font encoding, so LaTeX can hyphenate spanish. You should never use `\\`  at the end of a paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Prefacio}
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.

La técnica de la taquigrafía ha sido realmente útil en el pasado,
pero ahora, la mecanografía es una forma sencilla de expresar
conocimientos realmente rápido, hasta 150 palabras por minuto con
mucha práctica. blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla aun así...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe this is off-topic, but, when using `[T1]{fontenc}` and the package `anyfontsize`, when I type `\textsc{\fontsize{50 pt}{50 pt}\selectfont SOME TITLE}` the font of `SOME TITLE` is horrible, but when there is no `[T1]{fontenc}` the font style is alright.

Comment: If you use the default OT1 encoding, all hyphenation is wrong for words with accented letters. If writing in English that is OK, in other languages, less so. @Agente156